# Appending a row to the table jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to append a row using jQuery, but the row is not appending.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var counter = 1;
    $(function(){
         $('input#add_edu').click(function(){
         counter += 1;
         alert(counter);
         var paddingRow = "<tr id=\"padding-row\"><td id=\"padding-tab\"> </td> <td id=\"padding\"> </td><td id=\"padding-tab\"> </td><tr></tr>";

         var newRowLabel = "<tr><td class=\"label\">Course Name </td><td id=\"paddingtab\"></td><td class=\"label\">Institution Name</td><td id=\"paddingtab\"< </td><td class=\"label\">Start Date </td><td id=\"paddingtab\"< </td><td class=\"label\">End Date </td><td id=\"paddingtab\"></td><td class=\"label\">Percentage or CGPA </td></tr>";

         var newRowField = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="course_name_'+ count +'" id="course_name_'+ count +'" value=""></input></td><td></td><td><input type="text" name="college_name_'+ count +'" id="college_name_'+ count +'" value=""></input></td><td></td><td><input type="text" name="start_dt_'+ count +'" id="start_dt_'+ count +'"  value=""></input></td><td></td><td><input type="text" name="end_dt_'+ count +'" id="end_dt_'+ count +'" value=""></input></td><td></td><td><input type="text" name="cgpa_'+ count +'" id="cgpa_'+ count +'" value=""></input></td></tr>';


         $('#edu_table').append(paddingRow);
         $('#edu_table').append(newRowLabel);
         $('#edu_table').append(newRowField);

         });
        });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<table id="edu_table">
      <tr>
          <td class="label">Course Name </td>
          <td id="paddingtab" />
          <td class="label">Institution Name </td>
          <td id="paddingtab" />
          <td class="label">Start Date </td>
          <td id="paddingtab" />
          <td class="label">End Date </td>
          <td id="paddingtab" />
          <td class="label">Percentage or CGPA </td>

        </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to append rows to the table at the click of a button, but the rows are not appending. The rows appended fine until I appended the variable `newRowField`.

```
$('#edu_table').append(newRowField);
```

Comment: i'm trying to append it to a table
$('#edu_table').append(newRowField);

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the JS console? It looks like, at least, the last `value=""` needs some escaping; this isn't a valid string.

Comment: Actually, *none* of the `value` attributes are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has unescaped quotes in all of the `value=""` cases. You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using single quotes for the string, and double quotes for the HTML inside:

```
var newRowField = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="course_name_' + count + '" id="course_name_' + count + '" value=""></td>' +
  '<td></td><td><input type="text" name="college_name_' + count + '" id="college_name_' + count + '" value=""></td>' +
  '<td></td><td><input type="text" name="start_dt_' + count + '" id="start_dt_' + count + '" value=""></td>' +
  '<td></td><td><input type="text" name="end_dt_' + count + '" id="end_dt_' + count + '" value=""></td>' +
  '<td></td><td><input type="text" name="cgpa_' + count + '" id="cgpa_' + count + '" value=""></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Which is why it would still be helpful to (a) see your HTML and (b) see if there are any errors in your JS console.

Comment: You've also declared a variable named `counter`, but you're using a variable named `count` (undeclared) in the string definition. Again, things the JavaScript console would have told you about. Please look there.

Comment: From Webmasters StackExchange: [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Comment: Thank u Paul :) ... it worked.. so foolish of me to make the simplest of mistakes... sorry.

Comment: We *all* make these mistakes, and we all tend to see the code we *meant* to write, not the code we actually wrote. Just wanted to emphasize that the console can help you spot your mistakes much earlier.